# three js import .obj - mesh showing incorrectly

Tags: three.js, blender, .obj

I've exported 3d object as a .obj and it's showing up with the right end a bit messed up. I also tried a .fbx with the same results. Attached are some images of what is going on.

How can I fix this? It seems like it may be a flaw in the 3d object itself although if I re import the .obj (or .fbx) into blender it's fine (blender probably renders around simple issues)

Blender

[image: usmap 3d]

WebGL (three.js)

[image: webgl three.js map front]

[image: webgl three.js map side]

Comment: Click "trianglulate" when you export from blender? is the file available somewhere?

Comment: @gman I did triangulate w & without subsurf with no success

Comment: Well no one can help you without data. So voting to close as your quesiton is useless without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the beginning I figured this was a mesh issue. Three.js seems to be connecting all vertices of a mesh to each other, or something. Anyway, I decided to try splitting up the face with the `knife` tool. While I'm sure there is a better way, this works for now:

[image]